# Null Pointer Exception Error in java arrays

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have been doing this homework assignment for some time now and cannot figure out how to fix this null pointer error I am getting. I think it is an issue with int[] a in my code and it not being initialized before i call on a.length:

```
class target{

    int arraySearch(int a[], int target){
        for(int index = 0; index < a.length; index++){
            if(a[index] == target)
                return index;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public void main(String[] args) {
        target t = new target();
        int test1[] = {15,20,5,11};
        int test2[] = {15,20,7,11};
        System.out.println("Testing arraySearch with target = 5 and array of 15,20,5,11: " + t.arraySearch(test1,5));
        System.out.println("Testing arraySearch with target = 5 and array of 15,20,7,11: " + t.arraySearch(test2,5));
    }
}
```

If you guys could please help me and explain what is wrong that would be greatly appreciated. I am having this error on other parts of my homework and would like to fix them myself. All advice is appreciated.

Comment: Just as a heads up for the future, java classes should be capitalized like so `Target`

Comment: make your class public and main method static

Comment: Note that `main` should be defined as `static`. Other than that, the given code snippet runs fine as does not produce a `NullPointerException`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't get any null pointers. Just changed the signature to public **static** void main ...
Runs fine for me:
Testing arraySearch with target = 5 and array of 15,20,5,11: 2
Testing arraySearch with target = 5 and array of 15,20,7,11: -1